# Why Unity Timeline Activation track not working in Control Track?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using unity timeline active tracks. But sometimes they break and don't work.
This happens because when saving, the end values of the active track are recorded with a certain value after the decimal point.
But when this animation is opened by a technical designer on another computer, the value after the comma is overwritten and no longer coincides with the end of the track.
As I understand it, this is due to the serialization of floating point numbers on different processors.

To solve the problem, I wrote my own active track that makes a small gap in the end error, thereby protecting the floating number from rounding.
But it doesn't work if I play the timeline through control tracks.

Questions:
1 Have you encountered problems with rounding floats when working with timeline tracks?
2 Do you have any idea why the custom active track does not work in control tracks?

I am attaching the active track code:

```
    [TrackColor(1f, 1f, 0.0516715f)]
    [TrackClipType(typeof(CustomActivationClip))]
    [TrackBindingType(typeof(GameObject))]
    public class CustomActivationTrackCreator : TrackAsset
    {
        public bool PostPlayBackActivation;
        private CustomActivationTrackBehaviour _activationTrackBeh;

        public override Playable CreateTrackMixer(PlayableGraph graph, GameObject go, int inputCount)
        {
            var scriptPlayableBehacior = CustomActivationTrackBehaviour.Create(graph, inputCount);
            _activationTrackBeh = scriptPlayableBehacior.GetBehaviour();
            SetTrackSettingInBehavior();
            return scriptPlayableBehacior;
        }

        internal void SetTrackSettingInBehavior()
        {
            if (_activationTrackBeh != null)
            {
                _activationTrackBeh.PostPlayBackActivation = PostPlayBackActivation;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomActivationTrackBehaviour : PlayableBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField, Tooltip("Активация или деактивация во время воспроизводения клипа")]
    private bool ActivationInClip;

    [HideInInspector] public bool PostPlayBackActivation;
    private GameObject _targetGameObject;
    private bool _defaultActiveSelf;
    
    private PlayableDirector _playableDirector;

    public void SetActivation(bool value)
    {
        ActivationInClip = value;
    }


    public static ScriptPlayable<CustomActivationTrackBehaviour> Create(PlayableGraph graph, int inputCount)
    {
        return ScriptPlayable<CustomActivationTrackBehaviour>.Create(graph, inputCount);
    }


    public override void ProcessFrame(Playable playable, FrameData info, object playerData)
    {
        if (_targetGameObject == null)
        {
            GameObject trackBinding = playerData as GameObject;

            if (trackBinding != null)
            {
                _targetGameObject = trackBinding;
                _defaultActiveSelf = _targetGameObject.activeSelf;
            }
        }

        if (playable.GetInputCount() == 0)
        {
            Activate(_targetGameObject, ActivationInClip);
        }
        else
        {
            CheckPostPlayBack(playable);
        }
    }


    private void Activate(GameObject gameObject, bool activateFlag)
    {
        if (gameObject == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        gameObject.SetActive(activateFlag);
    }


    private void CheckPostPlayBack(Playable playable)
    {
        _playableDirector = playable.GetGraph().GetResolver() as PlayableDirector;

        if (_playableDirector == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var currentTime = _playableDirector.time;
        var durationTimeline = _playableDirector.duration;

        if (currentTime >= durationTimeline)
        {
            if (_playableDirector.state == PlayState.Playing && _playableDirector.extrapolationMode == DirectorWrapMode.Loop)
            {
                return;
            }

            Activate(_targetGameObject, PostPlayBackActivation);
        }
        
    }


    public override void OnBehaviourPause(Playable playable, FrameData info)
    {
        RestoreDefaultState();
    }

    public override void OnPlayableDestroy(Playable playable)
    {
        RestoreDefaultState();
    }

 
    private void RestoreDefaultState()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        if (Application.isPlaying)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (_targetGameObject != null)
        {
            _targetGameObject.SetActive(_defaultActiveSelf);
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomActivationClip : PlayableAsset
{
    [SerializeField] public bool ActivationInClip;

    public override Playable CreatePlayable(PlayableGraph graph, GameObject owner)
    {
        var playable = ScriptPlayable<CustomActivationTrackBehaviour>.Create(graph);
        CustomActivationTrackBehaviour clip = playable.GetBehaviour();
        clip.SetActivation(ActivationInClip);
        return playable;
    }
}
```

I wrote my custom activity track, it works correctly but only when playing timelines manually. If I use track control, the post-playbacks don't work.
I didn't find a way to affect the serialization.
I tried adding the GatherProperties method that the original track activity has, but that didn't help either.